# Does BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery() only discover un-paired devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have implemented the scanning for available bluetooth devices as described by the [Android SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices). It's working fine, but I only get informed about devices that are not already paired with my phone.

My question is, if this is the normal, intended behaviour?

It is okay if it is, I just have to be sure and the documentation does not say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the discovery reports any discoverable device it finds regardless of its pairing status.

Chances are that those paired devices you're not seeing are in fact not discoverable or there's some other reason for a device not being found.

Device discovery is not 100% reliable anyway: it's common to not discover devices even though they are discoverable and in range. If you want to increase the likelihood of discovering a certain device, run the discovery again.

Comment: Thanks! I realized, that it does not "discover" devices my phone is already connected to. Probably the device turns off its "discoverability" while it's connected.

Comment: Yes, it's not in the "inquiry scan" mode required for discoverability.